# base R: Aggregate and sum by two columns

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe

I am trying to use aggregate function to achieve same result as with SQL query however:

SQL:

```
sqldf(" SELECT
                PhotoID,
                UserID,
                SUM(Points) AS PhotoTotalPoints
            FROM Photos
            GROUP BY PhotoId, UserId")
116 186 rows.
```

R base:

```
aggregate(x = Photos["Points"]
  , by = Photos[c("PhotoId","UserId")]
  , FUN = sum
)
114 950 rows.
```

Using dplyr:

```
Photos %>%
    group_by(PhotoId,UserId) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(Points)) 
116 186 rows.
```

I am new to R. Tried to solve it in many ways but couldn't find any explanation in docs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a case where there are `NA` elements in one of the grouping columns and if there are NA, by default the `aggregate` removes that row.  In order to prevent that, we can use `na.action = NULL`

```
aggregate(Points~ PhotoId + UserId
    , FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE,  na.action = NULL
   )
```

Or it could be a case where some unused combinations are dropped with `drop = TRUE` for the data.frame method

```
aggregate(x = Photos["Points"]
   , by = Photos[c("PhotoId","UserId")]
   , FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE, drop = FALSE
   )
```